# Why do some of the repositories on docker hub not having dockerfile?

Tags: docker, bioinformatics, dockerhub

When I use the repo on docker hub, I saw some of them have the corresponding docker files. E.g. https://hub.docker.com/r/limesbonn/hisat2/dockerfile

But some of them don't. E.g: https://hub.docker.com/r/leanderd/single-cell-analysis

Could someone tell me why? Is there a way to get the dockerfile from a repo like this one: https://hub.docker.com/r/leanderd/single-cell-analysis? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There is no Dockerfile information in image file. It's the instruction to `build` layers of images. Therefore, there is no way Docker Hub knows which Dockerfile is for the image. It needs to be shared by the authors of the image.

If the author uploads Dockerfile to docker hub, they can use the automatic creating image mechanism. So, that's why you can see Dockerfile there.

Comment: This isn't quite right, DockerHub knows of the Dockerfile and still isn't showing it on the public view.  So... how do I include the Dockerfile in the "public" view in DockerHub?   Public view of repos says no Dockerfile, but DockerHub will show it under manage repo and is using it for autobuilds.   Something is off.

Comment: @Ryan, the image can be built outside, like in your local machine and pushed to DockerHub. It's true that if you are using DockerHub to build the image with provided DockerFile, they know and should be able to show the DockerFile.

Comment: Is there an environment variable or command line argument to "docker build" that instructs the image to be built with extra metadata pointing to the Dockerfile?   Maybe https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/advanced/ documents this, though it's not jumping out.